# wcf https with basic auth

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to consume a service over https with basic auth.

Binding:

```
<bindings>   
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="apiSoap11">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>   
 </wsHttpBinding>
```

```
<client>   
     <endpoint address="https://url"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="apiSoap11"
                contract="api"
      name="apiSoap11" />
    </client>
```

Code

```
var client = new Client();

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

var response = client.operation(request);
```

I am being returned a 500 error.

This request will works in SoapUi with basic auth and PasswordType ="PasswordText"

Any idea what I am missing.

Comment: Show your wcf client configuration from your config file or if you have done it code, show that code.

Comment: I have discovered the issues.  The response didn't contain a content type in the header.  So visual studio throws an error based on wcf not supporting a response without a content type when using the proxy generated by a wsdl.